# Scrolling UICollectionViewCell to background instead of vertical

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

I'm trying to recreate the Shazam Discover UI by subclassing `UICollectionView`/`UICollectionViewFlowLayout`.

I've got as far as paging the cells and making them the right size, however, I'm having trouble getting the cells to scroll to the background, as in, I don't have a clue on how to get it done, I've searched everywhere but can't seem to find it.

An **example** of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: example]

Any help/tips on how I could do this would be greatly appreciated.

---

**edit:** I ended up building my own solution:
https://github.com/JoniVR/VerticalCardSwiper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use third party libraries to achieve the same.
You may use [StickyCollectionView](https://github.com/matbeich/StickyCollectionView). This is an Objective C based library. I believe this one with some customization will help you to approve this.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot! This was actually exactly what I had been looking for! 
I was thinking about building it myself since I couldn't find something, but this is just perfect! 
The creator also seems to have made a [swift version](https://github.com/matbeich/StickyCollectionView-Swift) of the library, which is what I'm using so that's even better, going to check the code and see how it's done so I learn something too! Thanks a lot!